# How can i create Big 6 Box for Menu bar in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

This is my Web site menu bar,

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ResponsiveRetinaReadyMenu/

I want to create it in BootStrap.
i want just these 6 box in bootstrap.

How Can i create it in Bootstrap please help.

I don't want any javascript or hover css in bootstrap menu.
i just want these 6 big box  in bootstrap.
.How?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner well-large">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

      <div class=" nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav row row-fluid"   >
            <li class="btn btn-large img-polaroid">Home</li>
            <li class="well-large ">aboutus</li>
            <li class="well-large ">sevice</li>
            <li class="well-large ">portfolio</li>
            <li class="well-large ">blog</li>
            <li class="well-large ">contact</li>

        </ul>

      </div>

    </div>
</div>
```